# Problema al eliminar un elemento de un Hashmap java

Tags: java

No puedo eliminar elementos de un hashmap me pasa lo siguiente al usar this.alumnos.remove(objetivo); no elimina el elemento del mapa el codigo es el siguiente

```
package Principal;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class ABM_Alumno {


    public Map alumnos;


    public ABM_Alumno() {
        this.alumnos=new HashMap();

    }

    public Map getAlumno() {
        return this.alumnos;
    }

    public void setAlumno(Map alumnos) {
        this.alumnos = alumnos;
    }

     public Alumno obtenerAlumno(Double DNI){
       Alumno retorno =null;
       if(this.alumnos.containsKey(DNI)){
       retorno=(Alumno)this.alumnos.get(DNI);
       }
       return (retorno);


    public void crearAlumno( Double DNI, String Apellido, String Nombre, String Materia, double Nota, String Calificacion){
     if(!this.alumnos.containsKey(DNI))
     this.alumnos.put(DNI,new Alumno(DNI, Apellido, Nombre, Materia, Nota, Calificacion));



     }

     }
    public void eliminarAlumno (double objetivo) {

        if (this.alumnos.containsKey(objetivo)) {
     this.alumnos.remove(objetivo);
        System.out.println("el elemento se elimino correctamente ");}
        else {
        System.out.println("no se encontro el elemento  ");}
         }

    }
```

El mapa (alumnos) se carga correctamente y objetivo recibe correctamente la clave para eliminar el elemento pero por alguna razón el metodo eliminaralumno no elimina el alumno asi que le puse un if para comprobar cual era el error y resulto que no encuentra la clave que le paso que en este caso es objetivo alguien sabe  cual puede ser el problema ? 
 Clase alumno

```
package Principal;


public class Alumno {
    private double DNI;
    private String Apellido;
    private String Nombre;
    private String Materia;
    private double Nota;
    private String Calificacion;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Alumno{" + "Apellido="+ Apellido + "Nombre=" +Nombre+ "Materia="+ Materia + "Nota=" + Nota + "Calificacion=" +Calificacion+'}';
    }

    public Alumno(double DNI, String Apellido, String Nombre, String Materia, double Nota, String Calificacion) {
        this.DNI = DNI;
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Materia = Materia;
        this.Nota = Nota;
        this.Calificacion = Calificacion;
    }

    public double getDNI() {
        return DNI;
    }

    public void setDNI(double DNI) {
        this.DNI = DNI;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return Apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String Apellido) {
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getMateria() {
        return Materia;
    }

    public void setMateria(String Materia) {
        this.Materia = Materia;
    }

    public double getNota() {
        return Nota;
    }

    public void setNota(double Nota) {
        this.Nota = Nota;
    }

    public String getCalificacion() {
        return Calificacion;
    }

    public void setCalificacion(String Calificacion) {
        this.Calificacion = Calificacion;
    }





}
```

esto es lo que tengo en el boton agregar del panel que llama a la funcion crearalumno de la clase abmalumno que segun tengo entendido ahi  es donde se carga el map con el metodo put

```
String Apellido = this.txtApellido.getText();
       String Nombre = this.txtNombre.getText();
       String Materia = this.cbxMateria.getSelectedItem().toString();

        double DNI = Double.parseDouble(this.txtDNI.getText());
       double Nota = Double.parseDouble (this.txtNota.getText());
       String Calificacion = this.txtCalificacion.getText();
        if (this.txtDNI.isEnabled()){
            this.ABMALUMNO.crearAlumno(DNI, Apellido, Nombre, Materia, Nota, Calificacion);
            this.lstLista.setListData(this.ABMALUMNO.getAlumno().values().toArray());    
        }
```

Comment: Hola @Aster Phoenix, yo estoy usando tu código con un ejemplo más sencillo, en mi caso es un `HashMap<Double, String>`, para simplificar y ver si consigo reproducir tu error, pero a mí me funciona perfectamente, ¿Podrías subir la  clase Alumno, así como el método que rellena el Map para poder tener los datos con los que estas trabajando y así intentar reproducir tu error y solucionarlo? (La clase Alumno con los atributos me vale, para saber qué atributos estás utilizando y de que tipo son, y el map es para saber qué le estas pasando como clave en su creación)

Comment: @chikebox listo  ya lo agregue

Comment: Te recomiendo que ejecutes el código en modo depuración (debug) para que revises cuál es el valor del parámetro `objetivo` y si efectivamente hay una clave en el mapa con este valor. Tu código está perfecto tal y como lo muestras.

Comment: @AsterPhoenix, he intentado volver  a reproducirlo y no hay manera, me parece que no le estás pasando bien el dni a la hora de eliminarlo o no lo estas creando bien en el código que llama a tus métodos, porque he hecho una prueba rápida y no me da ningún problema el eliminar alumno. Como bien te ha dicho E. Betanzos, debuguea y mira que hace tu código exactamente.